# Find specific text and classify it ot specific column

Tags: awk, grep, separator

I have one problem, I would like to find the text in the text file and this text calsiffy it to the first column etc. I have 4 columns where is only one time in one row GI or HI etc. I would like to find from all text "chr" if I find it, I would like to classify it to the first column. After this I would like to find ENST and If I find it I would like to classify it to the second column, if the text is not in the row, the second column will be empty. After this same with GI and HI. Than input is the text with 4 columns, but it is not sorted and I would like to sort it lie this. At first column will be chr at second column will be ENST, at third column will be GI and at the fourth column will be HI.

INPUT:

```
> ENST  chr     GI  HI 
> chr   ENST    HI  GI 
> ENST  chr     HI  GI
> chr     .     HI  GI
```

OUTPUT

```
> chr   ENST  GI   HI
> chr   ENST  GI   HI
> chr   ENST  GI   HI
> chr   .     GI   HI
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Try improving the explanation.

Comment: Ok I would like to find from all file the text "chr" if I find it, I classify it to the first column and same will be for the text ENST. If it find it, it classify it to the second column etc...

Comment: Try updating your question with this comments, as well as indicating what have you tried so far. What, for example, if one `HI` was `TI`? Would there be a 5th column in the output?

Comment: I hope the update helps to better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
awk '{
      if(index($0,"chr")) {line="chr"}        else {line=" "}
      if(index($0,"ENST")){line=line " ENST"} else {line=line " ."}
      if(index($0,"GI"))  {line=line " GI"}   else {line=line " ."}
      if(index($0,"HI"))  {line=line " HI"}   else {line=line " ."}
      print line
   }' yourfile
```

**Output:**

```
chr ENST GI HI
chr ENST GI HI
chr ENST GI HI
chr . GI HI
```